# Exclude a file extension in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to get a file count in a folder, but I want to **exclude** files with extension jpg?

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Temp\\").Count();
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude just that extension or all Jpeg files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe)?

Comment: just that particular extension (.jpg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
var count = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\\Temp\\")
                               .Count(p => Path.GetExtension(p) != ".jpg");
```

Good luck!

Comment: +1 `GetExtension` is the correct way, instead of checking file name `EndsWith` ".jpg".

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `DirectoryInfo` object on the directory, and do a `GetFiles()` on it with a filter.

Answer (score 5):

Using Linq's `Where` method:

```
Directory.GetFiles(path).Where(file => !file.EndsWith(".jpg")).Count();
```

Comment: @John-89: Do you know why that's not recommended? Or have a link to more info? Just curious.

Comment: @John-89:  There's a big `[citation needed]` sign floating around in my head on this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string[] MultipleFileFilter(ref string dir)
{
    //determine our valid file extensions
    string validExtensions = "*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.gif,*.png";

    //create a string array of our filters by plitting the
    //string of valid filters on the delimiter
    string[] extFilter = validExtensions.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    //ArrayList to hold the files with the certain extensions
    ArrayList files = new ArrayList();

    //DirectoryInfo instance to be used to get the files
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);

    //loop through each extension in the filter
    foreach (string extension in extFilter)
    {
        //add all the files that match our valid extensions
        //by using AddRange of the ArrayList
        files.AddRange(dirInfo.GetFiles(extension));
    }

    //convert the ArrayList to a string array
    //of file names
    return (string[])files.ToArray(typeof(string));
}
```

Should work

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a simple LINQ statement to weed out the JPGs.

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\temp\\").Where(f => !f.ToLower().EndsWith(".jpg")).Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] extensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif" };

var files = from file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\TEMP\")
            where extensions.Contains((new FileInfo(file)).Extension)
            select file;

files.Count();
```

Comment: He's looking to exclude certain files, so you'd need to negate that `Contains` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ 'Where' clause to filter out files with not needed extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\\Temp\\").Where(f => !f.EndsWith(".jpg")).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use LINQ.

```
return GetFiles("c:\\Temp\\").Where(str => !str.EndsWith(".exe")).Count();
```